# Import Library into Robot Test

Tags: robotframework

I want to import library SeleniumLibrary into Robot test file but resulted not found. What could be the error?

I have installed SeleniumLibrary into C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages and set the environment variables. I"m using python 2.7.9

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  This is a simple test for Robot Framework
Library  SeleniumLibrary
#Set Selenium Speed 2 seconds

*** Variables ***
#${homepage} http://www.amazon.com
#${chrome_browser}   Chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Test title "Amazon"
    [Tags]  DEBUG

    Open Browser http://www.amazon.com chrome
    [Teardown]  Close Browser


*** Keywords ***
```

[image]

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: When you do a `pip list` does the module appear in the returned list of modules. If you have multiple python installations, are you sure you're using the right one?

Comment: When i run pip list, I found the robotframework-seleniumlibrary

Comment: Please read the error message carefully, and take it literally. It is saying that it can't find a keyword named `Open Browser http://www.amazon.com chrome`. Notice it's _not_ saying it can't find a keyword named `Open Browser`. That is a clue that shows you don't have enough spaces between each argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve by using four spaces between keywords and argument and argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your SeleniumLibrary looks perfectly fine, the problem is the way you are calling the KW.

The error you are getting here because of below line

```
Open Browser http://www.amazon.com chrome
```

There should be two or four spaces between Keywords and Arguments and Arguments and ... , otherwise it will treat whole line as KW , which never going to exist 
so change it like this

```
Open Browser    http://www.amazon.com    chrome
```

if it still throw an error, paste it here.

Comment: Yes, I have set the environment variable.

Comment: Error message is in the picture above.

Comment: You're slightly incorrect. Only two spaces are required, not four. You can use four, but that's not a requirement.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for correcting,will update my answer